# Shared preferences between classes (static)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, authentication, sharedpreferences

I have two classes, one loggedIn, and a User class. In the loggedIn class I want to show the shared preferences that I made when the user logs in.

```
loginPrefs = getSharedPreferences("loginpreferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor loginEditor = loginPrefs.edit();
loginEditor.putString("userID", userIDCrypt);
loginEditor.commit();
```

Now i want to make in the user class a getID() method, that I can call the method from every class with User.getID();. How can I do this?

I need the userID in multiple classes, so I want one activity (called getID e.g.) that gives me the user ID.

Comment: still unclear with question

Answer (score 1):

do like this make one class for your sharedpreference

```
       public class Session {

            private SharedPreferences prefs;

                public Session(Context cntx) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntx);
                }

           public void setusename(String usename) {
            prefs.edit().putString("usename", usename).commit();
            prefsCommit();
        }

        public String getusename() {
            String usename = prefs.getString("usename","");
            return usename;
        }
}
```

now after making this class when u want to use this use like this 
make object og this class like

```
  private Session session;//global variable 
session = new Session(cntx); //in oncreate
```

and now we set sharedpreference then use this like

```
session.setusename("USERNAME");
```

now when ever u want to get username then same work for session object and call this

```
 session.getusename();
```

**best of luck :)   same for password**

Comment: I cannot set the UserId in another class with Session.setUserId(123) becaus it is not a static method. And the userId has both numbers and characters..

Comment: chk my undated answer

Comment: And now, how do I get my username?

Comment: Then it says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getID()"

Comment: have u make a object of session in your current class dude

Comment: Yes, and after some adjustments, it doesn't give the error, but the application stopped working when i start it.

Answer (score 1):

try this in one Activity :

```
SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
sp = getSharedPreferences("enter", MODE_PRIVATE);
edit = sp.edit();
edit.putString("name", username);
edit.putString("pwd", password);
edit.commit();
```

in next activity :

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("enter", MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.getString("name", "default value"));
sp.getString("pwd", "default value"));
```

Comment: That works, but in multiple activities I need the userID, so I want one method that gets the userID. So i want a method called getID, and that I can use that in multiple classes..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if there is any syntax or compilation issues, just typing out of my head, and might make some mistakes. So in essence this is an approach that you can use to expose your prefs from one simple class and access it from any where.

```
public class MySharedPrefs {
    public SharedPreferences sp;

    public MySharedPrefs()
    {
        this.sp = c.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static String getStringFieldValue(Context c, String fieldName)
    {
        MySharedPrefs p = new MySharedPrefs(c);
        return p.sp.getString(fieldName, "default value");
    }

    public static void setStringValue(Context c, String fieldName, String value)
    {
        MySharedPrefs p = new MySharedPrefs(c);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
        edit = p.sp.edit();
        edit.putString(fieldName, value);
        edit.commit();
    }

}
```

Then use it like this in your activity:

```
MySharedPrefs.getStringFieldValue(this, "name");
```

You can the also expand on this class and add additional helper methods such as a `getUserName` or etc.

UPDATE:

When calling this from another static class, that class needs to have a reference to your applications context, you then need to provide that context to this function instead of using this.

```
MySharedPrefs.getStringFieldValue(context, "name"); //if your other static class has a property called context that contains your applications context
```

Comment: In what function did you use this class?

Comment: Just to expand, the this I am referring to would be the current activity's context, so this would work as is when used in `onCreate` for example, otherwise you need to get the context to where you are calling this function